# VLC does not read DVD .VOB

Tags: vlc, dvd

My laptop is an ASUS X555LJ and my UBUNTU is 14.04 LTS. I have a DVD, name: VTS VOB / type: MPEG, I can not see it with VLC. VLC recognizes it, but the cone of the volume is empty and also when DVD strats VLC starts to fibrillar. At the end I can not see anything. I uninstalled and reinstalled VLC again just in case it was not upgrade or misalignment. The result did not change. Can you advise me something?

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. When you can, accept the correct answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to install the `libdvdcss` application so that your system can read DVDs.

From the `/usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/README.css` file:

```
Many DVDs use CSS[0] as a form of a Digital Rights Management (DRM) to encrypt 
the content of Video DVDs. To play such discs a special library is needed to
decode them, libdvdcss.

Due to the legal limbo of libdvdcss in some particular juristictions, some
distributions including Debian do not distribute libdvdcss.
If it is legal for you to use CSS in your juristiction, you can:

  * Manually download and compile the source code from    
    <http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html>.

  * Use packages from derivatives that include libdvdcss.

 [0] <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System>
```

In the site of http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html there are instructions of how to setup a repository for installing `libdvdcss`.

From the above site:

> Our Debian/Ubuntu repository can be accessed by adding the following
>   lines to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
 deb http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/ /
 deb-src http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/ /
```

> And by running

```
 wget -O - http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/videolan-apt.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then their instructions end, and you finish the installation with the following lines:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libdvdcss2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wrote the first two lines of comand in the terminal and has appared "Deb comand not found". Some advice please

Comment: @CarloDeSantis That is because the `deb` line are not commands, but lines you add to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.  It stated it right above the lines themselves.  They are repositories for the application.  But, it looks as though you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```